# custom Plugin for CKEditor 3.x

Tags: ckeditor

this is the first time i am working with CKEditor.
any one can explain how to create plugin for CKEditor and how to insert plugin button into toolbar ?
Or Please give me a link to good tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, http://blog.tommed.co.uk/2009/09/07/how-to-create-a-ckeditor-v3-plugin

if not getting any help from this, let me know.

Also check http://www.sayopenweb.com/plugin-for-ckeditor/ for more options on CKEDITOR plugin.

Comment: this http://www.sayopenweb.com/plugin-for-ckeditor/ link gives a detailed explanation on more options in plugin and differnt types of plugin.. have a look guys!!

Answer (score 0):

There's a **[thread on the CKEditor forums](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15539)** which explains the same with a different set of examples. Consolidating the ideas from both these articles will help you understand the concept better.

Cheers,
m^e